# MutationObserver: Get a callback before mutation

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I would like to be notified just *before* and just *after* my DOM element has children added or removed. I can use MutationObserver to get callbacks afterward, but how can I get notified just before child nodes are added or removed?

Comment: I don't think such a notification exists.  Perhaps we could help if you described the problem you're actually trying to solve.